# Understanding internal IP

Tags: networking

Using my Android phone as hotspot, `route -n` shows me that its IP is 192.168.x.x and I can connect to it through `adb` or simply ping it (obtaining an answer).

On the other hand, my phone (in the About phone section) gives me the IP 10.x.x.x and I can in the same way connect to it or ping it as I did with the other IP.

My external IP is completely different (as shown by `showmemyip.com`)

Does the phone have two internal IPs? Are they both equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the IP shown in the "About phone" section is the IP address your phone received from the phone network, the fact that `showmemyip.com` shows a different IP address indicates that the network operator makes a Network Address Translation (NAT for short) between their customers and the internet. Such carrier-grade NATs usually don't have the ability to have customer-specified port forwardings set up.

That usually means you can make outbound connections, but since your 10.x.x.x IP is not unique world-wide, others on the internet cannot make inbound connections to your phone. For basic users this may be a security advantage, but this also means you cannot run any servers or peer-to-peer connections using that kind of connection. The only way others will be able to contact your phone or any device connected to it over WiFi is if the application you're using first makes an outbound connection to some server on the internet that will act as a "meeting point".

When you use the phone as a hotspot, it effectively becomes a router, with one IP address in the "outside" network (the mobile phone network in this case) and another in the "inside" network (the hotspot). But since the phone receives only a single IP address from the phone network, it must set up another NAT layer in order to be able to provide network connections to other devices. Such a "double NAT" situation can cause even more problems than a single NAT layer, e.g. with some (older) VPN solutions.

Often (but not always) systems that have multiple IP addresses will accept incoming traffic using any IP that belongs to the system, from any "direction". For example, if you use the phone's 10.x.x.x address to connect to it from the hotspot network, the phone's network drivers will detect that if the addresses were taken literally, the packet would need to go out of the external interface and then come right back in, and skip the unnecessary dog-leg.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your phone gives different internal IP's depending on how you connect to it, for example via USB cable or via WIFI.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have as many as internal/external IP address as many interface you have connected to a network. Every network you connected to assign you with a internal IP to communicate with you, and if the router/whatever is the main device is connected to Internet, it gives you a external IP address from the ISP.
For example I've an internal IP 192.168.0.107 with wlan0 and 10.42.0.x in usb0 (USB tethering). They are not same. Devices connected in same network 192.168.0.107 cannot communicate with your device using 10.x.x.x address and vice-versa.